# What happens if I change an Object that is inside a HashSet?

Tags: java, set, equals, hashset

I made an own class called Region and I store instances of Region in a HashSet. I use a HashSet, that there are no Objects which are equal in the list. The String name of a Region should be unique in the HashSet, so I have overriden the equals method.

My Question:

What happens if I store two regions with different names into the HashSet and then I make the different names equal (by a setter for the name)?

*This is no duplicate. The other question is about equal HashSets and not about equal objects in HashSets.*

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Don't do that.  Read the first "note" here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: "_What happens if ..._" You know you could just do it and see right?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402970/changing-the-elements-in-a-set-changes-the-equals-semantics

Comment: @Takendarkk I don't think this is the kind of thing one can just "try and see".  Probably if he changes the name, nothing will happen right away, but some future operation *may* now fail, but won't necessarily, and the OP wouldn't know which future operation to try.  Most "what happens if" questions could be addressed the way you did, **but not all**.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear.  If you're talking about changing the data that is used by equals/hashvalue *while* the object is in the set, then that's a no-no.  Anything that is done to the object to change it's hash value or response to *equals* while in the set breaks the "contract", and "undocumented behavior" is likely.

Comment: My Question is solved for me. I made the String name of the Region class final and removed the setter, so there is no option to change the name. 

I didn't know that there is no method for a String that changes the String itself, so a final String can never be changed. right?

Comment: `String` in Java is a **completely immutable** object. You can not change it in any way. Each method will instead create a new object with updated content. So yes, making the string `final` should be safe, the string can not be changed nor re-assigned anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

-- the Set Javadoc